# Nodejs Pagination using Shipment.all and Tracker.all

Tags: easypost

Appolgies i am quite new to Nodejs and programming, so Long story short:

Using the Easypost Nodejs API, I need to retrieve all Tracking Status 3 times a day using my Nodejs/express backend.

I hit a rate limit on my very inefficient way of retrieving all my tracking status'. Which is a seperate call for each Shipmentid to get the Trackingid which then gets the most recent status. Horrendously bad i know.

So i went to the Docs and thought, cool i'll do things seperately, get all my packages (myDB) then seperately get a list of all trackers then match up using shipment ID.

Problems...

1. i'm a newbie.
2. how to do multiple calls with pagination -> my first thoughts are to run an initial call to see if there are multiple pages, if "has_more" is true in then run as many times as needed on as many pages as i need for the last 2 months.
3. next problem... i seem to be missing the paging information in the response from the easypost API. In the docs there should be a response of 
   `{trackers:[all tracker info here], "has_more": true}`
   but there is is only an array of trackers in the response. even if i set the page size to 1 or 2...

Current code for getting the list of trackers:

````
      .get((req, res) => {
        console.log('Recieved - ' + req.method + req.originalUrl)
        easyPostAPI.Tracker.all(req.body)
          .then( response => {
            console.log('Sent - ' + req.method + req.originalUrl)
            res.json(response)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(400).json(err)
          })
      })```


hopefully it's not just me getting it wrong.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EasyPost [just released a 3.8.0 version of the node library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@easypost/api/v/3.8.0) in which you can access the `has_more` property on the array, like so:

```
api.Shipment.all({ page_size: 2, ... }).then(shipment => console.log(shipment.has_more))
```

---

In @easypost/api v4.0.0 there is likely to be a more convenient way to paginate, but for now, the above property should allow you to paginate.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it and releasing a new version! Is there anywhere Easypost discuss the planned changes, it would be interesting to know of developments!

Comment: Currently there isn't anywhere public where these things are discussed. Feel free to write into support help, or make github issues for feature requests.